# Free XPS file viewer and editor

Tags: windows, gratis

I need a free software which can be used to open, view, edit and print XPS files in my Windows system. Am not looking for a converter like XPS to PDF converter. Suggest a good software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what your looking for, it's called Master PDF Editor. Don't let the name fool you, it can work with XPS documents. With this software you can,

- Open XPS documents
- View XPS documents
- Edit XPS documents
- Print XPS documents
- Free to use

Somethings you should note about this software is that you **cannot**

- <strike>Save XPS documents</strike> (While you cannot use the Save As/Save feature within the program, you can print to an xps document to save it)
- <strike>Can only save as PDF documents & depending if you have a license or not, it will add a watermark (however it will not add a watermark if you print it)</strike>

## [Master PDF Editor](https://code-industry.net/get-masterpdfeditor/)

> Master PDF Editor is complete solution for editing PDF and XPS files.
>   You can insert, edit, remove, copy, add images or graphics. Export,
>   import, remove and change page layouts. Also Master PDF Editor
>   provides full functionality for changing PDF information, including
>   author, title, subject, keywords, creator, and producer information.
>
> [image: Master PDF Editor UI]